# How to compute $E[ (|X|) X]$ when $X \sim N(0,1)$?

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, integral

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does this mean?  "$E(|X|X)$" makes no sense: it looks like a typographical error for the expectation of $|X|$ or possibly for the expectation of $X$ itself, which you have specified as $0.$

Comment: It is the expectation of the absolute value of $X$ times $X$.

Comment: The reason that needs explanation is due to the natural interpretation of the second bar as meaning a conditional expectation.  Perhaps a well-placed pair of parentheses would help.

Comment: You are right. Thank you!

Comment: $|X|\cdot X$ is odd and its absolute value is simply $X^2$. Now given a standard normal is symmetric about 0 with finite second moment, the result should follow immediately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the symmetry of the standard normal distribution about $0$, if $X \sim N(0, 1)$, then $-X \sim N(0, 1)$ as well, so
$$
\begin{aligned}
E\big[|X|X\big]
&= P(X > 0) E\big[|X|X \,\big|\, X > 0\big]
+ P(X \leq 0) E\big[|X|X \,\big|\, X \leq 0\big] \\
&= \frac{1}{2} E\big[X^2 \,\big|\, X > 0\big]
- \frac{1}{2} E\big[X^2 \,\big|\, X \leq 0\big] \\
&= \frac{1}{2} E\big[X^2 \,\big|\, X > 0\big]
- \frac{1}{2} E\big[\left(-X\right)^2 \,\big|\, -X \geq 0\big] \\
&= \frac{1}{2} E\big[X^2 \,\big|\, X > 0\big]
- \frac{1}{2} E\big[X^2 \,\big|\, X \geq 0\big] \\
&= 0.
\end{aligned}
$$

This generalizes to the fact that if $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is an odd function (i.e., $f(-x) = -f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$) and $X$ is a random variable with a distribution that is symmetric about zero, then $E[f(X)] = 0$, provided the expectation exists.

Comment: Thanks! Last, in your generalization, how is it $E[f(X)]=0$? E.g. take $E(X^2)$ which for my random variable is $1$.

Comment: @econ86 the generalization is for odd functions; the function $x \mapsto x^2$ is not odd

Comment: Artem, Could you please explain what "$E[|X|X]$" means in your post and how "$X^2$" magically appeared in the second line?

Comment: @whuber I interpreted $|X|X$ in the question to mean the absolute value of $X$ multiplied by $X$; i.e., $|X|X = \text{sign}(X)X^2$

Comment: Thank you: I was stuck on interpreting the second bar as referring to a conditional expectation.